Prevent iPad from displaying on connected screen
Can I prevent an iPad from using an external screen as display when connected to that screen?
Motivation: I have a makeshift "docking station", where the same cable is used both for charging a computer and connecting to a display. Occasionally I need to charge an iPad with this cable (the only one available when I don't have a charger with me), but I don't want to mirror its screen on the display. Can I turn this off?
